# Modelio - class diagram -sequence diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram, modelio

Is it possible to create class diagram and sequence diagram on the same page(or can we link) in Modelio?

This is the class diagram I have created for the signUp
[image: This is the class diagram I have created for the signUp].

This is the sequence diagram I have created for the signUp
[image: This is the sequence diagram I have created for the signUp]

I am unable to find the actor icon in Modelio, I think it is not there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Modelio and I guess most (all) uml tools, it is not possible to create both class and sequence on the same diagram.

But Modelio allows you to link elements to other diagram by using "*Related Diagram link*".

[image]

Once your link is created between a model element, for example SignUp, and your diagram, for example your sequence diagram, you will then be able to navigate between them.

[image]

Finally, concerning the Actor creation, they can be create, of course, in UseCase diagram or under a Package in the model explorer and then referenced in sequence diagram.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This is much helpful!